# Add Validation for Registration Name Field

Tags: javascript, regex, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

I'm trying to add a validation rule to the registration name field. I've added in my validation.js file a function like:

```
this.setHandler('name',
function (value) {
regex=/^\S[\S ]{2,98}\S$/;
return regex.test(value);
}
);
```

In registration.xml (components/com_users/models/forms/), I have added to the name field:

```
class="validate-name"
validate="name"
```

But it's still not validating against the rule. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to get the validation to work was to add `aria-required="true"` to the field.

Answer (score 1):

what are the properties of your registrationfield?
At the first look of your regex I think minimum 2chars, maximum 98.
And you can add any symbol except whitespaces?

If I were you, I would set my registration field (if on username) to `\w\S{4,}`
`\w` is handy since it covers the expression `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
and if you add \S to it it covers the white space problem.
Also, why you use the "`\S`" on the beginning and the end of your expression is a little blurry to me.

Hope this helped ;)

P.S.: If you like a nice tool to practice/test your regex, I can recommand [Regex Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/). It's freeware and ez to use. Also, it gives you a lot of extra info on all kinds of different expressions

Comment: Hi, the property of the field is `<field name="name" type="text"
                  class="validate-fullname"
   description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_DESC"
   filter="string"
   label="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_LABEL"
   message="COM_USERS_REGISTER_NAME_MESSAGE"
   required="true"
   size="30"
                  validate="fullname"
  />
` however the problem is not really the regex, its getting the regex to "hook" onto the field. Thanks for the advice on the regex freeware ;), I'll check it out. Do you know what I'm doing wrong for the field to not validate according to the regex though?

Comment: why do you use a `<field />` ?  
why not just use `<form onSubmit=...><input /></form>`?
you should read [this article][1]. I know it looks very basic
But it still does the trick ^^

[1]: http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

Comment: This isn't my own form though. This is the standard joomla registration field ;), I am simply trying to add a validation rule to the name field. Just like the email, username and password fields.